# FTP Permissions

Tags: ftp

So I'm trying to setup a ftp service and send some files through my C# application to it. I can upload files to the main folder /www/ just fine, but I can't figure out how to give permission to the user "kmsuser" group "ftpaccess" to upload files in the subdirectories in /www/. I tried the chgrp command and it looked like it worked, but I still can't write anything in these folders.

[image]

So this is what my ftp settings looks like. I uploaded those .txt files through my C# application with no problems on /www/, but even though the folders 'Comercial', 'Financeiro' and 'RecursosHumanos' seems to be on the ftpaccess group, it still doesn't allow me to upload anything in it, even through the FileZilla software on linux. I'm also leaving the command line I used to include these folders to the group below.

```
root -i
chgrp ftpaccess /home/kmsuser/www/Comercial/
chgrp ftpaccess /home/kmsuser/www/Financeiro/
chgrp ftpaccess /home/kmsuser/www/RecursosHumanos/
chgrp -R ftpaccess /home/kmsuser/www/
```

Pls help!

Comment: Can you add the message (Error message ) that you are getting when you try transferring files to that directory.

Comment: The subfolders don't have group write access (drwxr **-** xr-x). Use `chmod g+w` to add that to each of those.

Comment: @Varad From the C# application I just get a generic message I made myself for when the files can't be uploaded, but through FileZilla or even navigating to the folder from my server ip address I get error 550.

Comment: @zagrimsan would you give me an exemple of implementation of this command? I don't quite know how to use it.

Comment: The syntax of `chmod` is just like `chgrp` for this part. Just append the folder name after `chmod g+w`.

Comment: @zagrimsan thank you so much! It's working now even through my C# app. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subfolders don't have group write permission (note the dash in the middle drwxr **-** xr-x). Use `chmod g+w` to add that to each of those (append folder name to the command just like with `chgrp`).